# Using PlotRangePadding given as a range with ListContourPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, padding

When I am trying to use PlotRangePadding with a fixed range (not symmetric with x and y axes) for a graphic generated by ListContourPlot, it is coming back with an error message that PlotRangePadding can only be either automatic or none.

Following is a small code to demonstrate the problem. Here, I want a padding at the bottom only, not a symmetric one around the whole graphic.

Will be thankful for any suggestion.

```
XX={{0.,0.,14},{0.,0.,2},{0.149508,0.076178,7},{0.153488,0.0498713,7},{0.156435,0.,4},{0.302952,0.0984348,7},{0.309017,0.,4},{0.444473,0.144418,7},{0.451668,0.0715374,7},{0.453991,0.,4},{0.574342,0.186615,8},{0.584501,0.0925761,7},{0.587786,0.,4},{0.689152,0.223919,8},{0.702713,0.111299,7},{0.707107,0.,4}};
    ListContourPlot[XX,ColorFunction->"TemperatureMap",PlotLegends->Placed[BarLegend[{0, 17, 34, 51, 67},LegendMargins->{{0,0},{10,5}},LegendLabel->"% output",LegendMarkerSize->150, LabelStyle->{Italic,Bold, FontSize->15, FontFamily->"Helvetica"}],{{0.1, 0.5}, {0.1, 0.1}}],PlotRangePadding->{{0, 0}, {0.1, 0}}, Frame -> False, BoundaryStyle->{Black, Thick}]
```

Comment: user49535, you have not accepted any of the answers to [your 37 questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/49535/user49535?tab=questions) over more than 2 years. May I suggest that you revisit your questions on the linked page to consider accepting answers or provide guidance on why none of the answers are not acceptable.

Comment: This is a bug. I recommend you report it to support.

Comment: I just figured out how to do it. Will do for all good answers in past. Thanks for letting me know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `PlotRangePadding` is hard-coded into `ListContourPlot` and Mathematica doesn't allow one to change this. But we can play with `PlotRange`:

```
ListContourPlot[XX, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
PlotLegends -> 
Placed[BarLegend[{0, 17, 34, 51, 67}, 
LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {10, 5}}, LegendLabel -> "% output", 
LegendMarkerSize -> 100, 
LabelStyle -> {Italic, Bold, FontSize -> 15, 
  FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}], {{0.1, 0.6}, {0.1, 0.1}}], 
Frame -> True, BoundaryStyle -> {Black, Thick}, 
PlotRange -> {All, {-0.1, All}}]
```

Maybe this is what you want.

[image]

Comment: PlotRange Worked !! Thanks a lot.

Comment: For the same graphic, how to smoothen the boundaries between two colors (contours) ? I tried InterpolationOrder from 1-10, but does not seem to make any difference !!

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** A work-around: Post-processing to replace the option value for `PlotRangePadding` (which, strangely, is `{{Scaled[0.02],Scaled[0.02]},{Scaled[0.02],Scaled[0.02]}}` regardless of how the user sets this option)

```
lcp1 = ListContourPlot[XX, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{0, 17, 34, 51, 67}, 
      LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {10, 5}}, 
      LegendLabel -> "% output", LegendMarkerSize -> 150, 
      LabelStyle -> {Italic, Bold, FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}], 
    {{0.1, 0.5}, {0.1, 0.1}}], 
   Frame -> False,
   BoundaryStyle -> {Black, Thick}, Axes -> True];

lcp1 /. HoldPattern[PlotRangePadding -> _] :> (PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0}, {.1, 0}})
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

Using

```
PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0}, {0.1, 0}, Automatic}
```

eliminates the error message and gives

[image]

However, `PlotRangePadding` option values are simply ignored by `ListContourPlot3D`.

Comment: Thanks ! It is not coming back with a error message now, but actually there is no padding below (or any other side) by using {{0, 0}, {0.1, 0}, Automatic}.

Comment: @user49535, you are right; that's strange.